# how to specify the input directory using any of the loop for multiple inputs?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

```
public class MultiXslt
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException,ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException 
    {
        //source xslt
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource("C:/Users/santhanamk/Desktop/newxslt/Xslt inputs/Idml0.xsl");

        DocumentBuilderFactory docbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = docbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        //source XML
        Document sourceDoc = dBuilder.parse("C:/Users/santhanamk/Desktop/newxslt/input.xml");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(sourceDoc);

        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                .newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory
                .newTransformer(stylesource);

        Document document = dBuilder.newDocument();
        DOMResult result = new DOMResult(document);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        Node resultDoc = ((Document) result.getNode()).getDocumentElement();

        System.out.println(resultDoc.getChildNodes().getLength());

        // print the result
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Transformer transformer2 = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer2.transform(new DOMSource(resultDoc), new StreamResult(writer));
        String s = writer.toString();     

    }
}
```

Actually I have one xml file and multi xsl file (C:/Users/santhanamk/Desktop/newxslt/Xslt inputs/list of xsl). when I give the xml and xsl0 as a input, I need to get the output as a string. So after I got the output,I need to give the same output as a input string for xsl1 to get another output(string). Then I need give the output as a input string for xsl2 to get another output. It should give the final output as xml, when the given source directory (C:/Users/santhanamk/Desktop/newxslt/Xslt inputs/list of xsl) doest have any new xsl file to load the output string!

Comment: so your question is, how you loop through your input xlst files?

Comment: If you have a directory of XSLT stylesheets, how do you determine the order of the stylesheets to be applied?

Comment: Actually,I have lot of xsl files in the name of idml0,idml1,idml2,idml3.....idml16 and single xml(input.xml).

Comment: Now im processing with 1 or 2 xslt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with the JAXP transformation APIs if you want to chain transformations then http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPXSLT8.html has an example to do that, using `XMLFilter`s created with `SAXTransformerFactory.newXMLFilter`.

Here is a sample Java code which shows how to use an array of stylesheet file names and set up a chain of filters:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLFilter;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;


public class JAXPTransChain1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        String[] stylesheets = new String[] {"sheet1.xsl", "sheet2.xsl", "sheet3.xsl"};
        String inputDoc = "input1.xml";
        chainSheets(stylesheets, inputDoc, new StreamResult(System.out));
    }

    private static void chainSheets(String[] stylesheets, String inputDoc, Result result) throws FileNotFoundException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {
        InputSource input = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(inputDoc));

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XMLReader reader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

        SAXTransformerFactory stf = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        XMLReader parent = reader;

        for (int i = 0; i < stylesheets.length; i++)
        {
            String sheetUri  = stylesheets[i];
            XMLFilter sheetFilter = stf.newXMLFilter(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(sheetUri)));
            sheetFilter.setParent(parent);
            parent = sheetFilter;
        }

        Transformer proc = stf.newTransformer();

        SAXSource transSource = new SAXSource(parent, input);

        proc.transform(transSource, result);   

    }

}
```

If the input is a sample like

```
<root>
    <foo>bar</foo>   
</root>
```

and the stylesheets do e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/node()[last()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:comment>sheet 1</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/node()[last()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:comment>sheet 2</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/node()[last()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:comment>sheet 3</xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the final output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <foo>bar</foo>   
</root><!--sheet 1--><!--sheet 2--><!--sheet 3-->
```

so the stylesheets have all been applied in the order of the input array. It should be easy to set up such an array from a listing of files in a directory, once you know which order you want.