# how do i merge multiple xslt files and xml files to input as one another to get the final output?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have three xsl files and one input file:

```
-input.xml process1.xsl output1.xml
-output1.xml process2.xsl output3.xml
```

now i want to just have it as:

```
input.xml process.xslt output.xml
```

process1.xsl, process2.xsl and their outputs should passed as the 
input to the xsl file and generate output.xml in the same process.xsl file.

how do i do this in xslt , i have referred to xslt apply imports but i am not getting proper reference for assigning the xml output as input for another xsl file all in one xsl.. can anyone help me out?

here i have invoked the input.xml and used process1.xsl for first step 
and the output generated is stored in the $content variable now i am stuck here that how do i import the process2.xsl and assing it to the previous output in variable $content, i am just able to display its output i want to assing it to next xsl file:

```
<xsl:import href="process1.xsl"/>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>



<xsl:template match="/">

 <xsl:variable name="content">
    <xsl:apply-imports/>
 </xsl:variable>

<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($content)/*" mode="m"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|*|text()" mode="m">

<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" mode="m"/>
</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>
```

something like this but this does not work?

Comment: Which XSLT 2.0 processor do you use? The latest processors support the `transform` function from https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-transform so that would be the most generic and powerful approach but requires using XSLT 3.0 like supported by Saxon 9. 7 PE or EE or the latest Altova. You will also need to explain/show which input `process.xslt` takes and how you want to treat the two results as one input.

Comment: Have you heard about "https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/" ? It is a queueing of transformations. Maybe it can be implemented in your environment.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i use Saxon HE 9.7.0 version file, also i have edited the question with code

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35845231/252228 how to chain transformations in Java. As for your snippets and doing it in pure XSLT 2.0, I think you would have to edit at least one stylesheet to add a mode or to provide a named template as an entry point, simply importing both modules does not allow you to choose which templates to use in which step of the transformation.

Comment: yes exactly that's what is happening .. i have tried using node-set which stores the output xml in a variable but i am not able to use it in case of pointing it to the exact xsl file.

Comment: Any general purpose language (Python, PHP, Java, C#, VB) can iterate through xsl transformations even calling command lines to your external XSLT processors and delete those temp "staging" output XMLs. As awesome as it is, XSLT is a special-purpose language. Now off to find the poster sending emails with SQL!

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 3.0 you could use the `fold-left` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-fold-left) together with the `transform` function (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-transform) to chain the transformations:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 version="3.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
 exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">

 <xsl:param name="sheet-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'process1.xsl', 'process2.xsl'"/>

 <xsl:param name="input-uri" as="xs:string" select="'input.xml'"/>
 <xsl:param name="input-doc" as="document-node()" select="doc($input-uri)"/>

 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

 <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="fold-left($sheet-uris, $input-doc, function($input, $sheet-uri) { transform(map { 'stylesheet-location' : $sheet-uri, 'source-node' : $input })?output })"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:comment select="'Processed by ' || document-uri(document(''))"/>
     <xsl:next-match/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously in a real transformation your stylesheet would do more than outputting a comment to indicate its processing the input but using above stylesheet called with Saxon 9.7 EE and `-it -xsl:process.xsl`, where the input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```

and the two stylesheets `process1.xsl` and `process2.xsl` are for instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array" xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="array fn map math xhtml xs">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:comment select="'Processed by ' || document-uri(document(''))"/>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--Processed by file:/SomePath/process1.xsl--><!--Processed by file:/SomePath/process2.xsl--><!--Processed by file:/SomePath/process.xsl--><root>
    <foo>bar</foo>
</root>
```

so the chaining is working.

Instead of passing the input document as a parameter you could also provide it as the primary input `-s` and change the main stylesheet to

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 version="3.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
 exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">

 <xsl:param name="sheet-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'process1.xsl', 'process2.xsl'"/>

 <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="fold-left($sheet-uris, ., function($input, $sheet-uri) { transform(map { 'stylesheet-location' : $sheet-uri, 'source-node' : $input })?output })/node()"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:comment select="'Processed by ' || document-uri(document(''))"/>
     <xsl:next-match/>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to chain transformations with Java then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35845231/252228 for an example.

Comment: hey thanks for your reference but i am constrained to use it in xslt 2.0 and SAXON HE edition.

Comment: @divya, unless the stylesheet modules already use modes or provide named templates to distinguish processing steps I think you first have to edit them if you want to do it in pure XSLT 2.0. In general importing two modules does not suffice to control the different transformation steps. If your question is about two particular stylesheets used with some particular input then consider to show the details in an edit to your question.

Comment: i have edited the question on what tried using mode.

Comment: @divya, well take your time to provide minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLTs and result you want versus result you get to allow us to understand where you need help.