# XSLT, Renaming Elements using mapping table based on Attribute's value

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

How to rename the elements according to a mapping table based on attribute's of the element?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
Maybe a XSLT 2.0 template and modifying the mapping table for better solution?

Many thanks in advance
Thomas

Original XML:

```
<transaction>
  <records type="1" >
      <record type="1" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item>223</item>
        </field>
        <field number="2" >
            <item>456</item>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>

  <records type="14" >
      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item>777</item>
        </field>
        <field number="2" >
            <item>678</item>
        </field>
      </record>

      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <item>555</item>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>
</transaction>
```

Mapping table:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
  <mapping type="1" from="record" to="first-record">
      <map number="1" from="field" to="great-field"/>
      <map number="2" from="field" to="good-field"/>
  </mapping>

  <mapping type="14" from="record" to="real-record">
      <map number="1" from="field" to="my-field"/>
      <map number="2" from="field" to="other-field"/>
  </mapping>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result after the transformation:

```
<transaction>
  <records type="1" >
      <first-record type="1" >
        <great-field number="1" >
            <item >223</item>
        </great-field>
        <good-field number="2" >
            <item >456</item>
        </good-field>
      </first-record>
  </records>

  <records type="14" >
      <real-record type="14" >
        <my-field number="1" >
            <item >777</item>
        </my-field>
        <other-field number="2" >
            <item >678</item>
        </other-field>
      </real-record>

      <real-record type="14" >
        <my-field number="1" >
            <item >555</item>
        </my-field>
      </real-record>
  </records>
</transaction>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet (executable with Saxon 9.8 any edition or Altova XMLSpy/Raptor 2017 or 2018) that transforms the mapping into an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet and then executes it with the `transform` function from XPath 3.1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math axsl"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="mapping">
        <mapping type="1" from="record" to="first-record">
            <map number="1" from="field" to="great-field"/>
            <map number="2" from="field" to="good-field"/>
        </mapping>

        <mapping type="14" from="record" to="real-record">
            <map number="1" from="field" to="my-field"/>
            <map number="2" from="field" to="other-field"/>
        </mapping>  
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>

    <xsl:variable name="stylesheet">
        <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
            <axsl:mode name="transform" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$mapping/mapping" mode="xslt-modes"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$mapping/mapping" mode="xslt-code"/>
        </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="mapping" mode="xslt-modes">
        <axsl:mode name="transform-{position()}" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mapping" mode="xslt-code">
        <axsl:template match="{@from}[@type = '{@type}']" mode="transform">
            <axsl:element name="{@to}">
                <axsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="transform-{position()}"/>
            </axsl:element>
        </axsl:template>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="xslt-code">
            <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="map" mode="xslt-code">
        <xsl:param name="pos"/>
        <axsl:template match="{@from}[@number = '{@number}']" mode="transform-{$pos}">
            <axsl:element name="{@to}">
                <axsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
            </axsl:element>
        </axsl:template>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:message select="$stylesheet"></xsl:message>
        <xsl:sequence select="transform(map { 'source-node' : ., 'stylesheet-node' : $stylesheet , 'initial-mode' : xs:QName('transform') })?output"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Remove or comment out the `<xsl:message select="$stylesheet"></xsl:message>` which is only in there to show the produced stylesheet code.

Of course the approach to transform the mapping into an XSLT stylesheet can also be used with XSLT 2.0 but then you need to run the created stylesheet from outside XSLT with e.g. Java or C# or by hand in your editor.

Comment: Hi Martin,
Great job.
Many thanks for the fast reply.
In fact, I forgot to mention, that I'm using a RESTful WebService written in Java 8 for transformation of the XMLs.
Sorry for the missing information.

I used your fantastic template for transforming some XML files in a small Java Application using command-line.
It works like a charm :-)
Thanks again!
Thomas

Comment: If I knew how fast I would get a solution here, I tried to describe the whole task at once.
The following XML is my start point.
- I have to remove all namespaces first.
- Making groups of Types {1, 2, 3, 4, .. 14}. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693291/xslt-xml-grouping-by-attribute-value)
 Other types like 200, 201 etc. would remain in root element (no groups needed for them).
- Subsequently your template would rename the elements according to the mapping table.
After some processing tasks I will have an XML, which then must be transformed back into the original format!!!!

Comment: <ab:transaction xmlns:ab="http://www...com/ab" >
  <ab:record type="1" >
 <ab:field number="1" >
  <ab:it>2</ab:it>
 </ab:field>
  </ab:record>

  <ab:record type="14" >
 <ab:field number="1" >
  <ab:it>7</ab:it>
 </ab:field>
 <ab:field number="2" >
 </ab:field>
  </ab:record>

  <ab:record type="14" >
 <ab:field number="1" >
  <ab:it>5</ab:it>
 </ab:field>
  </ab:record>

  <ab:record type="200" >
 <ab:field number="1" >
 </ab:field>
  </ab:record>

  <ab:record type="201" >
 <ab:field number="1" >
  <ab:it>P</ab:it>
 </ab:field>
  </ab:record>
</ab:transaction>

Comment: Should I create a new Question for that?
Would it be possible please to put me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance for your efforts

Comment: I think it is better to create a new question, if you want to chain stylesheets then with XSLT 3.0 you have the option of doing that with `transform` from within XSLT, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40866026/252228.

Comment: Okay Martin, thanks for your answer. I will create a new question. Best regards, Thomas