# XSLT 3.0, Converting XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I have an XML and an XSLT.
The Transformation works currently pretty fine.

How could I extend this XSLT for a result in JSON?

It could be even an separate XSTL for converting the XML result of the first XSLT into JSON.
I would then chain both together in Java.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Thomas

XMLs (original and after transformation):
[XSLT, Renaming Elements using mapping table based on Attribute's value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46708458/8760211)

XSLT 3.0: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709294/8760211

Comment: There a lots of ways to represent a particular XML document as JSON so simply telling us you want JSON output does really explain the requirement. XSLT 3.0 has support with https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-xml-to-json to convert that specific XML format to JSON, so if you want to use the built-in support you need to transform the current XML format to the one the `xml-to-json` function expects.

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thanks again for your last support and the current comment.
Actually, I have to convert the XML1, which you know, in something like this (XML2): https://stackoverflow.com/q/46805848/8760211
After some processing steps, the JSON file should be converted back into the original XML format (XML1): https://stackoverflow.com/q/46805848/8760211
I hoped that Jackson would do the job like the king Michael Jackson (RIP) did.
I can develop nice Java Apps, but XSLT is for me a surreal universe!
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to do it.

1. You can construct an XML document using the XML model for json and then use `xml-to-json()` to format it. For example, to construct the output `{"a":1, "b":2}`, you would first construct the XML document

   ```
   <fn:map>
     <fn:number key="a">1</fn:number>
     <fn:number key="b">2</fn:number>
   </fn:map>
   ```

   This gives you the ability to create any JSON output with precise control.
2. You can construct a data structure consisting of maps and arrays, and then serialize this using the JSON output method. For example, you could construct:

   ```
   <xsl:map>
     <xsl:map-entry key="'a'" select="1"/>
     <xsl:map-entry key="'b'" select="2"/>
   </xsl:map>
   ```
3. You can write the JSON "by hand" using the text output method.

Which you choose depends really on where the data is coming from.

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thanks so much for your answer.
I hoped it was there a simpler way to do this, because the real XML, which has to be converted, could have Records of types {200, 201, 500, …} other than those defined in the mapping table here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46709294/8760211
`<xsl:param name="mapping">…</xsl:param>`

Those special custom Records should be converted in JSON and back again without any changes.
I don't know about the inner structure of those custom Records.
To be continued..

Comment: I should only be aware of the outer shell, more precisely something like these following Records:
`<record type="200" >…</record>
<record type="500" >…</record>`

I used Jackson for converting at Java Level.
The result was a JSON, where the attributes appeared as Elements and not as attributes of other values.
It seems to become a hard day for a developer on this planet :-)
Thanks again
Thomas

Comment: Hi Michael, 
you are right!
I had to stress a bit more the existence of the custom defined Elements in the question.
Sorry for the lack of these details.
I tried to split the tasks in much smaller pieces.