# XSLT, concat values to comma separated string and filtering unnecessary elements

Tags: xml, xslt

How to convert XML1 to XML2?

*In a further step (not part of this question) I should convert XML2 in JSON.
The comma separated values must be then appear as arrays:*

```
{111, 222};
{456};
{777,555};
{777,555};
{678};
```

Thanks so much in advance for your efforts, Thomas

XML1:

```
<transaction>
  <records type="1" >
      <record type="1" >
        <field number="1" >
            <subfield>
                <item>111</item>
                <item>222</item>
            </subfield>
        </field>
        <field number="2" >
            <subfield>
                <item>456</item>
            </subfield>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>

  <records type="14" >
      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >
            <subfield>
                <item>777</item>
                <item>555</item>
            </subfield>
        </field>
        <field number="2" >
            <subfield>
                <item>678</item>
            </subfield>
        </field>
      </record>
  </records>
</transaction>
```

XML 2:

```
<transaction>
  <records type="1" >
      <record type="1" >
        <field number="1" >111,222</subfield>
        </field>
        <field number="2" >456</field>
      </record>
  </records>

  <records type="14" >
      <record type="14" >
        <field number="1" >777,555</field>
        <field number="2" >678</field>
      </record>
  </records>
</transaction>
```

Comment: Actually, I tried to solve this in Java. But after 1,5 days I realized that it wasn't a really good approach. As I'm an absolutely newbie in XSLT, I hoped of some hints which put me to the right directions. Thanks in advance, Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find a good book on XSLT and have a good read of it. See [Where can I find a good tutorial on XSLT files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511759/where-can-i-find-a-good-tutorial-on-xslt-files) for suggestions.

Secondly, learn about the Identity Template....

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With that in place, you are half-way there! You only need to then worry about transforming the `subfield` elements. That means you just need to add a template matching `subfield` which selects the `item` nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="subfield">
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, better still, if you can use XSLT 2.0, do this...

```
<xsl:template match="subfield">
    <xsl:value-of select="item" separator="," />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="subfield">
        <xsl:value-of select="item" separator="," />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does assume one `subfield` per `field` though.

Comment: Hi Tim,
You and the other good people here rescue me from the misery.
Thanks so much my Friend!
I'm really beginning to understand the nature of the XSLT, mainly the meaning of the mother of all templates:
    `<xsl:template match="@*|node()">..</xsl:template>`
And thanks for the other hints and links.
Best regards
Thomas
---
Actually I wasn't supposed to develop XSLT, but just RESTful Web Services.
And now within two weeks I have to learn high level XSLT 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 and realize complex templates! 
Two days until the weekend.
I must survive this week somehow :-)

Comment: The `version` on the stylesheet using `<xsl:value-of select="item" separator="," />` was supposed to be `2.0`, no? And Thomas seemed to use XSLT 3.0 in other places so the identity template could be expressed more compact as `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in that version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the version number. I have amended my answer.