# Error ! "Premature end of file"

Tags: html, xml, jsp, servlets, xslt

I have total 3 files as follows

1. data.xml
2. render.xslt
3. last.xslt

see image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wln3h.png

My first task is to take **data.xml** and **render.xslt** as input which will give output as **All.xml** after that below given servlet will process the **All.xml** and **last.xslt** as input which will give output response to Http Request.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

/**
 *
 * @author Shubham Dalal
 */
public class Manager extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException,
    java.net.MalformedURLException {

        // Tell the response object that our servlet returns HTML
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        // Ask for a response stream
        PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
        // This block tries to open our XML and XSLT files
        // which may throw an exception, thus the try..catch
        try {
            // Get a empty transform factory (factory pattern)
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            // Get the actual server path for XML and XSLT files
            String loc = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "/";

            Source sdk2 = new StreamSource(
                new URL("file", "", loc + "full.xml").openStream());
            Source Main = new StreamSource(
                new URL("file", "", loc + "Main.xslt").openStream());
            // Generate the transformer
            Transformer Maintransformer = tFactory.newTransformer(Main);
            // GRAND FINALE!
            // Perform the transformation, send output to the browser
            Maintransformer.transform(sdk2, new StreamResult(output));

            // Get the XML input document and the stylesheet using
            // the string loc that holds the path information,
            // creating a JAXP Source instance
            Source sdk = new StreamSource(
                new URL("file", "", loc + "sdk.xml").openStream());
            Source list = new StreamSource(
                new URL("file", "", loc + "list.xsl").openStream());
            // Generate the transformer
            Transformer listtransformer = tFactory.newTransformer(list);
            listtransformer.transform(sdk, new StreamResult(new File("", loc + "full.xml")));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            output.write(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(output);
        }
        output.close();
    }
}
```

#### The problem is that i don't how to write whole code in single servlet that performs First task and then process second task i.e. All.xml and last.xslt to provide html output.

i'm newbie to servlets.

#### Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35845231/252228 on how to chain two or more XSLT transformations.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen can you please show me whole code in single servlet. I don't know how to implement that one.